# Visual Studio Pre-build event to change executable name

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, pre-build-event

I have a program in which I run several instances of simultaneously, but with different configurations. I have each configuration tied to a different Application configuration(ie the default for VS are debug and release).

How do I make each configuration have a different executable name on build??

Comment: Why does it have to be pre-build?

Comment: while building, how do you decide which configuration are you selecting

Comment: Does not have to be prebuild event. Whatever works. I just do a build all on the configurations and it builds everything